# How do I define the source location for a file based dependency in gradle

Tags: java, dependencies, gradle

I have a gradle build script that defines a file dependency.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile files('lib/test/wibble-1.0.jar')
}
```

I have a source jar for the library that I would like to add to the dependency so that with in eclipse I can navigate to the source.  How do I add that information to the dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Adding source Jars for artifacts not resolved from a Maven repository requires some scripting of `eclipse.classpath` (see `EclipseClasspath` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html)). It could look like this:

```
import org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.*

eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged { Classpath classpath ->
                classpath.entries.each { ClasspathEntry entry ->
                    if (entry instanceof AbstractLibrary && entry.library.file == file("lib/test/wibble-1.0.jar")) {
                        entry.sourcePath = fileReferenceFactory.fromFile(file("lib/test/wibble-1.0-sources.jar"))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could generalize this code to add all source Jars in the `lib` directory that adhere to some naming convention.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears the the Eclipse Plug-in (as opposed to the gradle generated eclipse project) does not seem to see this in the dependency model, which is what I am really after.

Comment: Make sure to configure import to run Gradle tasks before/after import. Another thing you could try is to use a `flatDir` repo and use the exact same naming pattern for the Jars and sources Jars in your `lib` directory as Maven would. If this doesn't solve the problem, report your use case over at http://forums.gradle.org.